# How to add images into database using SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have been trying to make a webtoon website by following [Corey Schafer's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH). I am now at the point of my project where I want to have the ability to add my webtoon chapter images instead of posts as in the tutorial.

The problem I have is that I tried hard-coding in the image file and as a result this happens:
[image]

But I want the ability to be able to add in the respective picture for each chapter.

First I create my Chapters model using Flask to store them:
`models.py`

```
class Chapters(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
     title= db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
     date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
     image_file = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)

     def __repr__(self):
         return f"Chapters('{self.title}','{self.date_posted}','{self.image_file}')"
```

Then in my I render this in my `routes.py`:

**I am using list to display the Chapters and the date posted**

```
chapters = [
    {
    'author': 'Benson Jin',
    'title': 'Chapter 1',
    'date_posted': 'April 20,2018'

    },

    {
    'author': 'Benson Jin',
    'title': 'Chapter 2',
    'date_posted': 'April 21,2018'

    }

]
```

My home page is then rendered through

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html',chapters=chapters)
```

`home.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for chapters in chapters %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ chapters.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ chapters.date_posted }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ chapters.title }}</a></h2>
    <img   src="/static/chapter_images/chapter1.png" width="500" height="300"  >
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor  %}
{% endblock content %}
```

As you can see from my html, it uses a for loop to print out the chapters information (date,title,name). However, since I hard-coded the image into my html this results in image being printed twice. Would my approach be to store my images into a data base or something else?
Please let me know if you need more details. This is my first time building a website so yeah.. :(

Comment: You already have a field in your database (`image_file`) which (probably) stores the path of the image. Just use that field when rendering. Avoid hardcoding

Comment: Uhh could you explain what you mean? Sorry, still a bit new to this stuff. Do I add the image_file into my db? And then instead of rendering chapter, render the image_file?

Answer (score 0):

Change your image path like this.

```
<img src="/static/chapter_images/{{ chapters.image_file }}" width="500" height="300">
```